# No sound in my HP 2000-2116tu laptop

Tags: drivers, sound

I am using HP 2000-2116TU laptop and I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 in it (I'm dual booting it along with windows 7). The problem is that there is no audio(no audio in speakers as well as headphone). The sound card in my lap is Realtek HD audio. I guess Ubuntu is not recognising my sound card. Maybe  it is the lack of proper drivers. So please help me to fix this problem. The sound card is fine since it works perfectly in windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu provides its own sound driver,to listen sound you have to install proper plug-ins from ubuntu side.So you simply open any media file and then search for plug-ins in net via that media player.